# Bash scripted curl commands producing different results than manual runs

Tags: bash, curl

I have a text file of roughly 900 cURLs to run.  They are pretty hairy, with tons of quotes, apostrophes and other special characters.

To run them I have been trying to create a bash script to loop through the list:

```
#!/bin/sh

OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS="&&&"

echo "getting started"

cat staging_curl_script|while read line
    do
        $line
    done

echo "done"
```

Unfortunately I have had an unusual issue.  commands that run fine in the command prompt are returning the "file name too long" error.  I echoed out these commands from the script and compared them to the manually run command, and they are identical.

Any idea why I am seeing different results?

Comment: Don't use `echo` to debug things like this. Use `set -x`. The lines in the file are *full* curl command lines to execute? Is `&&&` an actual value or just something "safe" that won't mess the content up? You almost certainly want to add `-r` to the `read` call. (You can also localize the `IFS` change to just the `read` call with `while IFS= read -r line` too.)

Comment: That all being said if the original file is all valid shell commands (one-per-line) why not just execute the file as a script and be done with it? Trying to stuff commands into shell variables is generally a non-starter. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 for discussion about it.

Answer (score 0):

silly mistake here, needed `bash -c "$line"`

Comment: Do you mean double quoted? `"$line"`?